# Has been studying or Have been studying?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

When using both the perfect aspect and also the progressive aspect for my verb “to have been studying”, should I use the present tense *has* or the past tense *had* here?

1. She **has** been studying there for eight years then she **moved** to another school.
2. She **had** been studying there for eight years then she **moved** to another school.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of 'moved' gives the sentence past tense so it should be 'had'.

> The Past Perfect expresses the idea that something occurred before
>   another action in the past. It can also show that something happened
>   before a specific time in the past.

[Past Perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html)

Answer (score 0):

She had been studying there for 8 years then she moved to another school. That is technically correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/218250)

Comment: Uh… what are you talking about, Cascabel? All three answers are both correct and clear.

If you doubt that, please explain why…

Answer (score 0):

The second of the two, for the reasons already given. You could say "she has studied...and will be moving...". The second sentence is more an indicator of the past. You could say "She has been studying there for six years and still is studying there". You wouldn't use "had" in that sentence, because "had" signals cessation of the thing that the person "had" been doing. Or you could simply say "She studied..."